# SVN Repository Proxy

Tags: svn

I have a problem similar to the one described in ths SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286586/mirror-svn-repository-write-through-proxying, but with more restrictive circumstances.

We are working along side a different development team who have the 'master' SVN repositry that they are using, we have access to this via VPN but would like to proxy this internally to a 'slave' repository. Workflow would be something like this:

- Copy from the 'master' repository to the 'slave' repository
- We work in the 'slave' repository until we are happy
- Check the changes back in from the 'slave' repository to the 'master' repository

So the 'slave' repository is essentially acting as a branch from the 'master' - we have full control over the 'slave' repository server, but want to avoid any changes to the 'master' server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Better use DVCS (git, mercurial) for such things.
2. You can have checked out working copy of master repository and apply patches from slave ones. My way of doing such things is using `git-svn`, `git format-patch` and `git am`. Of course this can be done without git too.

Comment: Thanks for that, have set up a git repository over the top of an SVN working folder and seems like it should do the trick, maybe not the ideal solution but should work well enough

Comment: Don't accidently check ".git" directory into SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

\3. You may also experiment with setting up "reverse proxying" in Apache (with mod_svn) at "/branches/master_reposiutory" to "https://master-repository/trunk". But you should experiment first with toy repositories, I don't know whether it is a good scheme. Everything except of "/branches/master_repository" will be like usual mod_svn, and "master_repository" will look at the remote thing.